# How to center div that has other div classes inside of the main one?

Tags: html, css

I am adding background images for my home page buttons so the code is (see below). After I added the additional divs (inside the main myclass div) then everything left aligns and I want to make it centered. How can I do that?

```
<div class="myclass">
        <a href="link"><div id="Home"></div></a>
        <a href="link"><div id="About"></div></a>
        <a href="link"><div id="FAQ"></div></a>
        <a href="link"><div id="Contact"></div></a>
</div>

.myclas {
    background:#F5CA0D;
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
text-align: center;
}

#Home {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("images/Home.jpg");
    float:left;
  clear:right;
}

#Home:hover {
  background-image:url("images/Home-hover.jpg");

}

#About {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("images/About.jpg");
    float:left;
  clear:right;
}

#About:hover {
  background-image:url("images/Oahu-hover.jpg");

}

#FAQ {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("images/FAQ.jpg");
    float:left;
  clear:right;
}

#FAQ:hover {
  background-image:url("images/FAQ-hover.jpg");

}

#Contact {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("images/Contact.jpg");
    float:left;
  clear:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend the spelling mistake .myclass firstly and then try below

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxfvqfLs/5/)

**CSS**

```
.myclass {
    background:#F5CA0D;
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.myclass > a, div {
    display: inline-block;

}

#Home {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");
}

#Home:hover {
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");

}

#About {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");

}

#About:hover {
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");

}

#FAQ {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");

}

#FAQ:hover {
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");

}

#Contact {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:211px;
  height:109px;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image:url("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png");

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="myclass">
        <a href="link"><div id="Home"></div>4</a>
        <a href="link"><div id="About"></div>3</a>
        <a href="link"><div id="FAQ"></div>2</a>
        <a href="link"><div id="Contact"></div>1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Parlanchina updated to center correctly, please check if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have the rule `float: left` on every element. I would start by getting rid of that. you probably dont need the `clear` either.

Comment: babpacih, when I remove it then they all align one under another. I want to align them next to each other instead. thanks.

Comment: to do that you need to remove the margins from each of them and set them to `display: inline-block` [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakesezkoala/wxfvqfLs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you have `float:left` everywhere, change this, and also `clear:right` is of no use here, you don't need it either. make the script short as possible to make it easy to load in browser

Answer (score 0):

Firstable, the name of your class is not the same as the html (s is missing to myclas).

Than, you can't center the main div because you're using 100% for the width. You can use a fixed width and than a margin:0 auto; It would work.

Comment: Then relates to time.
Than is used to introduce a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling in your CSS `.myclas {`